# Probability sequences?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I had a dream last where someone presented the first 6 terms of a sequence:

"1, 7, 12, 15, 19, 20, 22, ..."

I was then asked to find the nth term, and after a few seconds in dream world, had realised that it was generated by rolling a dice.

The first term is the first roll, and then each term after that is found by adding on the amount that appears on the next roll of the dice.

I was thinking how you might express this as an nth term rule, and thought I'd ask the stackexchange community if there is any notation for this sort of thing?

I feel quite stuck because as far as I'm aware there is no notation for expressing 'the number generated from a dice roll'.

I thought maybe something like '{${n=1,2,3,4,5,6;P(n)=1/6}$}'?

If there is anything people know about sequences of this type, or this overlap between probability and sequences I'd be really curious to know more!

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to find the $n$-th term with a  deterministic formula because it's a dice.

Answer (score 2):

You can say something like 
$$a_n=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$
mentioning that $x_i$ are i.i.d. random variables drawn from the uniform distribution on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

As Dietrich mentions in his comment, you cannot write a deterministic formula.